# parallax scrolling scrollview viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, parallax

I have a viewpager with 3 fragments whose backgrounds are transparent, so you can see through them and right now I have a static image as bg for the activity hosting the viewpager.

What I want to achieve is that when I scroll the viewpager the background image would scroll horizontally at half speed with the viewpager. I know this is possible with a recyclerview + scrollview vertically, but can't figure out how to do it with viewpager + scrollview horizontally (or maybe there's a workaround?).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

please try out this solution.
https://github.com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager
I think you just need rewrite some things, but the main principle is:
in touch controller count scrollView and move background image during this scrolls.
Another way is to cut image between pages.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to implement it but the background doesn't show at all now. I tried a few forks which can be found online but neither of them worked either.
Could you maybe elaborate on what has to be rewritten or do you have an idea where the background not showing problem might stem from?